# WCF Session without Credentials

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Is it possible to configure a WCF service to use sessions, and also not to require the client to send any credentials?

If so, how should the `bindings` section of the service's `App.config` file look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.reliablesessionbindingelement.aspx to establish a session using the WS-ReliableMessaging spec. I don't see why this should require authentication.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="BasicWithWSReliable">
     <reliableSession />
     <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```